# Does running top and/or gnome-system monitor slow down your computer?

Tags: system-monitor, top

In a computer with multiple monitors, is there any harm in or reason not to keep a terminal with `top` or `gnome-system-monitor` open on a screen? I like knowing if some software I'm running is starting to mess up the system, so I like to keep it up all the time. Is there any reason not to? If there is, can you explain how it slows the computer down?

Comment: `top` should be pretty light and not affect the system much, if at all. However, the `gnome-system-monitor` can be quite heavy on weaker systems, especially the graphs tab. I had seen occasions where it uses up half of the CPU resources just to draw those graphs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every process consumes resources from your system but `top` is not going to be in the top 5. Gnome system monitor can be as it is more than just showing information, it also creates graphics and other ways to show you data that all will need resources.

You can use this to view the top 10 memory consuming processes:

```
ps -eo pmem,pcpu,vsize,pid,cmd | sort -k 1 -nr | head -10
```

Also have a look at `htop`, it is a little bit quicker when starting.

> I like knowing if some software I'm running is starting to mess up the system, so I like to keep it up all the time. I

I do not think that will work. When there is a spike, you might get to the screen that has top before the spike ends. You really should set up some sort of log to be able to see what spiked the system.

You are better of with ...

```
 sar -u 1 0 -f /var/log/sar
```

This will show once per second (1) forever (0) cpu usage (-u) and it is all saved in /var/log/sar for future reference.

Some remarks:

- that log on 1 second interval will grow. Quick.
- sar also eats resources. More when it has to work a lot.

... so choose a more sane interval.

- sar might actually already log to /var/log/sa/.

Comment: I think "1 second interal" (fourth line from bottom) should be "1 second interval"...